# Reproducible package install

Tags: package-management

Is there a way to keep track of packages you install on Ubuntu?

Like say "npm install blah" and then you can have blah both installed in the current dir and documented in your package.json. Short of using something like Ansible, is there to keep track of the packages I install/uninstall via apt (no need to keep track of default packages coming from the base install) into a file that I could then keep under revision control?

Comment: There is `/var/log/apt/history.log`. It includes `Install` and `Remove` lines for packages that have been installed or removed. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really, although this is really interesting, I guess I could write a service around that file...

I was hoping for a file keeping track of all the packages installed and remove since install, and be able to re-use that file to re-install those packages for a new install. I really like how npm manages package.json for a project, only adding packages that are installed successfully, this is the model I am looking for.

Comment: You should look into `dpkg --get-selections` and `dpkg --set-selections`.

Answer (score 0):

Which packages are installed or removed on a Ubuntu system is tracked by the `dpkg` package.
To reproduce a set of installed packages from one machine to another, do this on the first machine:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > installed-packages
```

This will write out all installed (and removed) packages to a file `installed-packages`. Transfer this file over to the other machine, and there do:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < installed-packages
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

(you may need to manually install a package called `dselect` first)
This will set the selected packages to "install" and, in the second step, actually install them.

Doesn't work for machines with different `sources.list` files, or when PPAs on the first machine have been installed, but in general you are replicating the installation of the first system to the second.

Comment: Unfortunately, this includes everything in the base OS, kernel packages etc... Packages that I don't need and don't want to carry from one version of the OS to the next.